# What is the English name for Chitra Rajmah?

Tags: beans, language

What is this variety of kidney beans called in English? We call them "Chitra Rajmah" in Hindi.
http://www.helloorganic.com/Rajma_chitra.html
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pinto beans.  Throw in a few more foods in Hindi, and I'll translate them too, while I'm here; I've got good reference books handy with names in both English and Hindi.

Comment: I didn't know how to add that image there. :)

Comment: When posting or editing, click the little icon (image or picture) that looks like a painting. It's right next to the {} symbols.

Comment: I know about the IMG tags, but I didn't know how to get the photo from another website in these IMG tags. Perhaps we simply include the url :eek:

Comment: and why did you label this as Indian cusine? :) Don't Americans cook this lentil?

Comment: Stack Overflow has a relationship with the Imgur image hosting service.  It uses them and brings up a mini upload page if you click the icon.  Or, you can upload there and use the URL if you prefer.

Comment: I labelled it as "indian cuisine" because it needs tags besides "beans" and I couldn't think of a better tag to use.  I'm trying to decide on one now.

Comment: @AnishaKaul let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/681/discussion-between-bobmcgee-and-anisha-kaul)

Comment: It is taking a long amount of time to load that login page of chat link, besides _food_names_ is nice tag, at least better than the previous one. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: So will this be called "Pinto beans" or "Pinto kidney beans"?

Comment: Just pinto beans.

Answer (score 1):

we have reached three varieties of common beans (Phaseolus vulgaris) commonly used in India while researching for website.

kidney beans -  rajma.

pinto beans - chitri wala rajma, printed rajma.

Navy bean - white rajma, white beans, safed rajma.

You can found more [about Indian ingredients in English to Hindi here.](http://spiceteller.com/all-spices/)