# What is sour cream called in Hindi?

Tags: sour-cream, language

I need to know it so that I can purchase it from the market. What is sour cream called in Hindi?

Comment: Wasn't this offtopic? Huh!! http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15871/what-is-the-english-name-for-chitra-rajmah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Khatti malai or khatti makkani.

Comment: Could you include your source, Spicy? Others including myself would love to have that resource.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez What source? Perhaps I speak Hindi - थोडा़ खट्टा मक्खन ;-)

Comment: Well, that's a possibility, of course, but my version of Google does not find the word "makkani".  Did you mean "makhani" and if so, does that mean "khatti makhani", or sour butter is the same substance as sour cream?

Comment: @KristinaLopez Makkani, Makhani can also mean cream.

Comment: @KristinaLopez You need to remember than the English versions of Sanskrit words are *phonetic* and therefore spellings can and will vary considerably.

Comment: Makkhan is butter. Malai is cream. @KristinaLopez